# Raspberry Pi 3 Power Issue

Tags: pi-3, power, power-supply

I am using Raspberry Pi 3 Model B for my project purpose. The Pi 3 works fine when it is powered through a 5V/2A charger and I am able to use the inbuilt Bluetooth and Wifi using it, but when I try to use the GPIO pins, I am not getting proper output voltage. For eg. when I use a multi meter to check the output voltage at 5V pin or 3.3v pin, the meter shows reading around 0.1V to 0.3 V. Is it due to the 5v/2a charger,which is not providing the required power? Or, is the problem with the Raspberry Pi board? Should I buy a 5V/2.5A charger as per the Pi3 specifications?

Answer (score 1):

Two possibilities.

1. You have a faulty meter (needs a fresh battery perhaps)
2. You are not measuring the voltage across the correct pins

I power my Pi3B from a phone charger providing about an amp (the Pi probably uses about half an amp).  I don't have any power hungry devices plugged in to the USB sockets.

Answer (score 1):

The power requirements of the Raspberry Pi increase as you make use of the various interfaces on the Raspberry Pi. Your current charger should work fine with current scenario of pi interface.
Is it fast charging adapter??
I will suggest go with 5-5.3V/2.5A rated charger.